# Get the first '1's on condition if it followed by consecutive 5 '0's in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe which has event column as 0's and 1's for every month on a user_id. I need to select the event as 1's which must have exactly pervious rows as 5 0's. If this condition satisfies then only get the first 1's ? actually identifying the patterns of 5 0's and next 1's

I tried is by using rank but its not working on whole dataset for me. Any inputs will be helpful.

for eg. if you have dataframe as:

```
 df:
 user_id   event
   1         0   
   1         0
   1         0
   1         0
   1         0
   1         1
```

Now i need to find out this kind of pattern in my dataset it can be available at place for my records of data set having specific user id. As for as user id i can have max 48 records i need to find such groups of pattern out it. Between this if 1 occurs then i am not interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve here, but with the input data provided, you can get one's complement of event and then find cumulative sum over window of 5 rows preceding current row. 
Check this and let me know,

```
>>> df.show()
+---+-----+
| id|event|
+---+-----+
|  1|    0|
|  1|    0|
|  1|    0|
|  1|    0|
|  1|    0|
|  1|    1|
|  1|    1|
|  1|    1|
|  2|    1|
|  2|    0|
|  2|    0|
|  2|    0|
|  2|    0|
|  2|    0|
|  2|    1|
+---+-----+

>>> df = df.withColumn('r_event',F.when(df.event == 0,1).otherwise(0))
>>> w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('id').rowsBetween(-5,-1)
>>> df = df.withColumn('c_sum',F.sum('r_event').over(w))
>>> df.show()
+---+-----+-------+-----+
| id|event|r_event|c_sum|
+---+-----+-------+-----+
|  1|    0|      1| null|
|  1|    0|      1|    1|
|  1|    0|      1|    2|
|  1|    0|      1|    3|
|  1|    0|      1|    4|
|  1|    1|      0|    5|
|  1|    1|      0|    4|
|  1|    1|      0|    3|
|  2|    1|      0| null|
|  2|    0|      1|    0|
|  2|    0|      1|    1|
|  2|    0|      1|    2|
|  2|    0|      1|    3|
|  2|    0|      1|    4|
|  2|    1|      0|    5|
+---+-----+-------+-----+

>>> df.where(df.c_sum == 5).select('id','event').show()
+---+-----+
| id|event|
+---+-----+
|  1|    1|
|  2|    1|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: glad to know !!